Accuracy for Permutation Test is very high
I am a bit confused as to what is happening with my classifier.
I have a dataset of ~220 features and about 4000 trials. Classes are perfect balanced, and I'm doing a simple binary classification task using a SVC with an L1 norm.
I get decent accuracy when I do LOOCV but when I want to check permuted data, I also get the same CV accuracy +/- 2%, which is ~ 67%.
This feels odd since when I run a simulation with random data but preserving basic structure (220 X 4000) I do not get accuracy significantly above 50%. To me this means overfitting is not automatically occurring, but it makes me really confused as to why I'm getting these weird results. It also surprises me that the mean of the permutation tests would be fairly far from "true chance" (50%)
Is there something I am missing that would explain this?
